# Intel OneApi Vtune profiler not supporting my microarchitecture

Tags: intel, hpc, intel-vtune, sycl

Im using the intel-oneapi/vtune module so aren't the OpenCL drivers already bootstrapped to it, just like the intel-oneapi/compiler.

The reason I ask is when I run this vtune command:

vtune -collect hotspots -result-dir=vtune_result01  ./test_HPCCG 20 20 20

from the terminal I get this:

```
vtune: Warning: Hardware collection of CPU events is not possible on this system. Microarchitecture performance insights will not be available.
```

I still get some results:

```
    CPU Time: 24.350s
        Effective Time: 11.637s
        Spin Time: 11.001s
         | A significant portion of CPU time is spent waiting. Use this metric
         | to discover which synchronizations are spinning. Consider adjusting
         | spin wait parameters, changing the lock implementation (for example,
         | by backing off then descheduling), or adjusting the synchronization
         | granularity.
         |
            Imbalance or Serial Spinning: 2.912s
             | The threading runtime function related to time spent on imbalance
             | or serial spinning consumed a significant amount of CPU time.
             | This can be caused by a load imbalance, insufficient concurrency
             | for all working threads, or busy waits of worker threads while
             | serial code is executed. If there is an imbalance, apply dynamic
             | work scheduling or reduce the size of work chunks or tasks. If
             | there is insufficient concurrency, consider collapsing the outer
             | and inner loops. If there is a wait for completion of serial
             | code, explore options for parallelization with Intel Advisor,
             | algorithm, or microarchitecture tuning of the application's
             | serial code with VTune Profiler Basic Hotspots or
             | Microarchitecture Exploration analysis respectively. For OpenMP*
             | applications, use the Per-Barrier OpenMP Potential Gain metric
             | set in the HPC Performance Characterization analysis to discover
             | the reason for high imbalance or serial spin time.
             |
            Lock Contention: 0.230s
            Other: 7.859s
        Overhead Time: 1.712s
            Creation: 0.968s
            Scheduling: 0.745s
            Reduction: 0s
            Atomics: 0s
            Other: 0s
    Total Thread Count: 32
    Paused Time: 0s

Top Hotspots
Function                                            Module                         CPU Time  % of CPU Time(%)
--------------------------------------------------  -----------------------------  --------  ----------------
sched_yield                                         libc.so.6                        7.859s             32.3%
_INTERNAL65c1faee::tbb::detail::d0::machine_pause   libtbb.so.12                     5.643s             23.2%
[TBB Scheduler Internals]                           libtbb.so.12                     2.726s             11.2%
Intel::OpenCL::Utils::AtomicCounter::operator long  libcpu_device.so.2021.13.11.0    1.490s              6.1%
tbb::detail::r1::market::process                    libtbb.so.12                     0.722s              3.0%
[Others]                                            N/A                              5.910s             24.3%
```

It displays that the correct cpu so im sure its detected the device. Or is this just not supported on this:

```
Top Tasks
Task Type         Task Time  Task Count  Average Task Time
----------------  ---------  ----------  -----------------
tbb_parallel_for    11.442s      34,018             0.000s
tbb_custom           1.246s       6,388             0.000s
Collection and Platform Info
    Application Command Line: ./test_HPCCG "20" "20" "20" 
    Operating System: 5.4.0-167-generic DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04 DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"
    Computer Name: ncc1
    Result Size: 24.8 MB 
    Collection start time: 11:17:45 18/03/2024 UTC
    Collection stop time: 11:17:57 18/03/2024 UTC
    Collector Type: User-mode sampling and tracing
    CPU
        Name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Processor code named Skylake
        Frequency: 2.100 GHz
        Logical CPU Count: 32
        Cache Allocation Technology
            Level 2 capability: not detected
            Level 3 capability: available
```

If someone could also explain what the above input means. I dont get why I get the above instead of actual functions. Thanks!

Comment: Do you use a VM? It looks like so based on the provided information. Do you have sufficient privileges (e.g. root)? Can you specify the CPU name in `/proc/cpuinfo` in the question?

Comment: I dont use a VM. I dont have root privileges so I cannot access /proc/cpuinfo. What does this have to do with the above.

Comment: Without privilege or a special rights provided to a classical user VTune cannot access hardware counters for security reasons since it could be used AFAIK for example for side channel attacks or even worst. The CPU information in `/proc/cpuinfo` generally does not require advanced rights. In fact, such file is used by many tools (including profilers) to track information about the CPU. Here, VTune seems to detect a generic CPU. Most profiling operations are AFAIK not available on such detected CPU. Hardware counters are dependent of the CPU architecture so it needs to be detected first.

Comment: If you do not own the machine, you should ask admins if VTune is properly configured to access hardware counters. It is sometimes intentionally not enabled for security reasons (especially on cluster and supercomputer where multiple users can share the same machine or to avoid leaks from the kernel which is a problem for some admin processes). This is sad as it can prevent developers/researchers to micro-optimize codes to specific HPC platforms.